# In emacs, how do I align closing parentheses with the start of the opening line?

Tags: emacs

The default indentation style for multi-line function calls in many emacs modes is to align the closing round bracket with the other arguments to the function, thus:

```
function_one(
    arg1,
    arg2
    );
```

I would prefer it if the closing bracket aligned with the start of the line that contains the opening bracket.  For example:

```
function_one(
    function_two(
        f2_arg1,
        f2_arg2
    ),
    f1_arg2,
    f1_arg3
);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I have been ignoring the same urge for *years*! Today is the day to fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- For the many modes derived from CC Mode (for example, c-mode, java-mode, php-mode), customise `c-offsets-alist` so that `arglist-close` is set to `c-lineup-close-paren`.
- For cperl-mode, customise `cperl-indent-parens-as-block` to true.
- For cperl-mode, GNU Emacs 24.3+, set `cperl-close-paren-offset` to the negative of `cperl-indent-level`
- For perl-mode in GNU emacs 24.3 and greater, customise `perl-indent-parens-as-block` to true.
- For python-mode, this behaviour is found in GNU emacs 24.3 and greater.

You can customise a variable by typing `M-x customize-variable`.  Alternatively, add the following lines to your `~/.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(arglist-close . c-lineup-close-paren))
(setq cperl-indent-parens-as-block t)
(setq perl-indent-parens-as-block t)
```

Comment: Is there any way of getting this to work in python-mode with Emacs 23.1.1?

Comment: The solution for Emacs 23.1.1 is simply to get the latest python-mode.el [here](https://launchpad.net/python-mode).  Untar it in your ~/.emacs.d directory, then in your .emacs file, add this: `(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.3"))
(require 'python-mode)`

Comment: And how do I make this work in **C** or **C++**?

Comment: Is there any way to get the *other* style in `python-mode` on Emacs >= 24.3?

Comment: To get the C solution to work I had to put it in a function executed as part of c-mode-common-hook